# How to refer to the language and grammar specifications of a formal text?

Tags: single-word-requests, formality

The word will be used to describe a specific way of referring to things. It is similar to the language lawyers use in court.

It will be for the specification of the rules of engagement for those participating in an assessment of a company's work environment (they will be from outside the company).

Example: Read the [insert-word-here] document to know what you should and shouldn't do.

Comment: Lawyers and the like use _legalese_, but to know if that is what you are looking for, you should add some more detail to your question.

Comment: I think we still need more details, as it is still  unclear what you're looking for. Can you add a sample sentence?

Comment: Please also describe the "specific action" you mentioned. That may be relevant, for examples, if they are managers the best word may be 'managerial'.

Comment: **Please don’t write answers in comments.** It bypasses our quality measures by not having voting (both up and down) available on comments, by not being editable by the community for improvement, and by not having a visible edit history.. Comments are to be used only for clarifying and improving the question; please don’t use them for other purposes.

Comment: Are you looking for the name of the document that describes the "rules of engagement" or a name for the language that is used in that document? (There are answers that address both of these.)

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of a [business process](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ar-procdoc/index.html)?

> The purpose of your guide is to communicate the process management guidelines to support a specific process. The document essentially serves as the source of guidelines to be followed worldwide. The guide can be used by a wide range of audiences -- business units, partners, customer service, regional process leaders, or anyone who is involved in the specific process outlined in the guide.

Or a [process specification](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28636/process-specification):

> A process specification is a method used to document, analyze and explain the decision-making logic and formulas used to create output data from process input data. Its objective is to flow down and specify regulatory/engineering requirements and procedures.

Or a [Standard Operating Procedure](https://tallyfy.com/standard-operating-procedure-sop/) (SOP):

> Standard operating procedures are written, step-by-step instructions that describe how to perform a routine activity. Employees should complete them in the exact same way every time so that the business can remain consistent. Standard operating procedures help maintain safety and efficiency for departments

Or a [formal specification](https://www.unf.edu/~ncoulter/cen6070/handouts/specifications.pdf) (often used in hardware and software development):

> A formal software specification is a statement expressed in a language whose vocabulary, syntax, and semantics are formally defined.

Answer (score 0):

[Terminology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminology)

> Terminology is a discipline that systematically studies the "labelling or designating of concepts" particular to one or more subject fields or domains of human activity. It does this through the research and analysis of terms in context for the purpose of documenting and promoting consistent usage. (Wikipedia)

- Read the *Terminology* document to know what you should and shouldn't do.

Answer (score 0):

Is “How to refer to the language and grammar specifications of a formal text” to be interpreted as a request for a single-word definition or what, please?

Either way did you notice no difference between “a specific way (of referring to things)” and “a specification of (a way of referring to things)”?

How could “they will be from outside the company“ ever make any difference?

One - very clearly not the best - answer would be “Read the [official] document to know what you should and shouldn't do” and however bad that is, please note this is one of those rare contexts in which contractions like “shouldn't ” will not do.

That said, what would be wrong with “Read (the) document Title of Document to know what you should (and shouldn’t) do”, please?

That is to say, why look for difficulties when it would be much easier to avoid the Question?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly better way to describe this document, or at least a reasonably common one, is [*[topic] **nomenclature guide***](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="nomenclature+guide") or [***guide to*** [topic] **nomenclature**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q="guide+to+*+nomenclature").